# PHP If function - OR

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

This code for WordPress when you visit the category page that is "Cheshire" it will show the weather widget but I also want it to show on "Cheshire Sport" without putting all the code in twice is there a simple way to use it for both?

```
<?php 
$current_category = single_cat_title("", false);
if ($current_category == "Cheshire"){
?>
<div id="c_022b685c6534fb12881f4e5a78e6f32a" class="ancho">
    <h2 style="color: #000000; margin: 0 0 3px; padding: 2px; font: bold 13px/1.2 Verdana; text-align: center; width=100%">
    <a href="http://www.forecast.co.uk/northwich.html" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none; font: bold 13px/1.2 Verdana;">
    The weather for Cheshire</a></h2>
    <div id="w_022b685c6534fb12881f4e5a78e6f32a" class="ancho" style="height:100%"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.forecast.co.uk/widget/loader/022b685c6534fb12881f4e5a78e6f32a"></script>
<?php
}
else {
    echo "";
}
?>
```

Does anyone know an easy way to do this?

Comment: yes. create a function in functions.php which takes an argument, a string in your case and depending on string does something.

Comment: Try `if( ( strcasecmp($current_category,'Cheshire')==0 ) || ( strcasecmp($current_category,'Cheshire Sport')==0 ) ){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$current_category = single_cat_title("", false);
if ($current_category == "Chesire" || $current_category == "Chesire Sport")
{
?>
<div id="c_022b685c6534fb12881f4e5a78e6f32a" class="ancho">
    <h2 style="color: #000000; margin: 0 0 3px; padding: 2px; font: bold 13px/1.2 Verdana; text-align: center; width=100%">
    <a href="http://www.forecast.co.uk/northwich.html" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none; font: bold 13px/1.2 Verdana;">
    The weather for <?= $current_category ?></a></h2>
    <div id="w_022b685c6534fb12881f4e5a78e6f32a" class="ancho" style="height:100%"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.forecast.co.uk/widget/loader/022b685c6534fb12881f4e5a78e6f32a"></script>
<?
}
?>
```

This is an adequate way to do it if you only have two `$current_category` values that would result in this being displayed. However, chaining `||` statements can be messy and wouldn't be ideal way to do multiple if statements.

Answer (score -1):

You could encapsulate the functionality into a function, which you can then call whenever you need it. See an example below:

```
<?php
   function displayWidget()
   {
      $current_category = single_cat_title("", false);
      if ( ($current_category == "Cheshire") || ($current_category == "Cheshire Sport") )
      {
        return 
        '<div id="c_022b685c6534fb12881f4e5a78e6f32a" class="ancho">'.
         '<h2 style="color: #000000; margin: 0 0 3px; padding: 2px; font: bold 13px/1.2 Verdana; text-align: center; width=100%">'.
           '<a href="http://www.forecast.co.uk/northwich.html" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none; font: bold 13px/1.2 Verdana;">'.
             'The weather for Cheshire'.
           '</a>'.
          '</h2>'.
        '<div id="w_022b685c6534fb12881f4e5a78e6f32a" class="ancho" style="height:100%"></div>'.
       '</div>'.
       '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.forecast.co.uk/widget/loader/022b685c6534fb12881f4e5a78e6f32a"></script>';
      }

      else
      {
         return "";
      }
   }
?>
```

Then whenever you need it, just call it like so: `<?php echo displayWidget(); ?>`